# Reading a textfile database and displaying the results

Tags: android, xml, database, parsing, text-files

I have a database thats in the form of a text file, my job is to parse the txt file and display the data in a listview. I have no idea where to start.

Heres an example entry.
"|9251115|,|0|,|DETAILS|,||,||,|Heading      Price    Text    Text |,||,||

Where each || represents a field. There are also html tags between heading price and the text (p,b)

My first idea would be to parse it similarly to an xml document, i.e have it create a new line where it starts with a "|", fill it with everything in between and end the line when it reaches the next "|". But I still have no concrete idea on how to do this.

EDIT:

Taking it one step at a time for now. Using stringtokenizer to read it line by line and remove "," for a start. Ran into a problem, the textview to display the results is displaying false for some reason instead of the scanned text. here's my code if anyone needs a good headscratcher.

Context myContext;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    st = new ArrayList<property>();

    try
    {
         InputStream is;
         is = myContext.getAssets().open("rooms.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
         String read = br.readLine();
         while( read != null)
         {
             StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(read,",");
             {
                 while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                 {
                     String a = st.nextToken();
                     String b = st.nextToken();
                     String c = st.nextToken();
                     String d = st.nextToken();
                     String e = st.nextToken();
                     String f = st.nextToken();
                     String g = st.nextToken();
                     String h = st.nextToken();
                     t.setText(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d+" "+e+" "+f+" "+g+" "+h);
                 }
             }
         }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can definitely implement your own parser using pure Java code, you should consider using a SQLite database (1) to store your data, which will allow you to insert, delete, modify and query much more easily.

If you database comes in that format from an external source, I'd write a one-time parser that parses the data and inserts it into the SQLite database for future use.

Remember that the CPU on Android devices is slower than your average PC CPU, so if you are parsing large amounts of data in this format all the time, your app might become very slow. Hence my suggestion of converting it to a database.

Another option you have in this case is using XML like you said, because there are ready-to-use parsers out there. But the advice about performance remains: you should really avoid reparsing the data all the time and, instead, store it in a ready-to-use format.

(1): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at the moment this text file is stored locally on my laptop but the original file is up on filezilla, the final version of my work will have to access that file I am guessing, will an sqlite database still work under those circumstances? Also do you know any good tutorials?

Comment: Apologies if I come across as too amateurish

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do,

```
Have an object with getter/setter
Have a list intialized
1) You  need to use StreamReaders/Bufferedreader to read the file 
2) If each is not empty
  2a) Use StringTokenizer to parse the string with "," as delimiter
  2b) Set tokenized values to object
  2c) Add object to list
3) return the list created in above step.
```

Note: If large data you need to be careful while reading entire file, you may get OutofMemoryError.

Comment: Do you have a very simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Bruno Oliveira gave very good advice.

You can parse your file by reading it line by line and then use [string.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method, as result you will have all your data in an array where you can easily read and put into a list view or move it to a sqlite database.